# Finding curvature for $y = \sin ( -2x )$ at $x =\pi/4$

Tags: calculus, curves, curvature

The answer is 4, but I got 1. I said $r(t)=<t,\sin(-2t)>$ and the $|r^\prime(\frac{\pi}{4})|$ is equal to 1. I also got 1 for $T^\prime(\frac{\pi}{4})$ but none of this information matters because I got the question wrong, can someone help me out please? thanks. Also, ideally, use the $\dfrac{|T^\prime|}{|r^\prime|}$ formula.

Perhaps, I shouldn't have translated it into a rectangular form? But I have only been taught how to compute curvature using a rectangular form.

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What is $T'$ and $t'$?

Comment: @SarGe its the unit vector of the derivative of r, so you take the derivative of r(t) with respect to t then divide it by its magnitude$(|r'(t)|)$ to get its unit vector, that is T'(t).

Comment: -@Bandoo, however you've got the answer. Leave it. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function can be parameterized as:

$${\displaystyle \mathbf{r}(t)\,=\,{\begin{pmatrix}t\\\sin(-2t)\end{pmatrix}}}$$

The curvature is given by :

$$\kappa = \frac{\|\mathbf{r}'(t)\times\mathbf{r}''(t)\|}{\|\mathbf{r}'(t)\|^3}$$

$${\displaystyle \mathbf{r}'(t)\,=\,{\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\cos(-2t)\end{pmatrix}}}$$
$${\displaystyle \mathbf{r}''(t)\,=\,{\begin{pmatrix}0\\-4\sin(-2t)\end{pmatrix}}}$$

Setting $x \mapsto \frac{\pi}{4}$ follows:

$${\displaystyle \mathbf{r}'(\frac{\pi}{4})\,=\,{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}}}$$
$${\displaystyle \mathbf{r}''(\frac{\pi}{4})\,=\,{\begin{pmatrix}0\\4\end{pmatrix}}}$$
Now use the formula:

$$\kappa = \frac{\|\mathbf{r}'(\frac{\pi}{4})\times\mathbf{r}''(\frac{\pi}{4})\|}{\|\mathbf{r}'(\frac{\pi}{4})\|^3}=\frac{\left\|\,{\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\4\end{pmatrix}} \right\|}{\left(0^{2}+1^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}=4$$

Comment: How are you taking **cross-product** of two dimensional vectors?

Comment: You are embedding $\mathbb R^2$ into $\mathbb R^3$ without mentioning it.

Answer (score 2):

Straightforward. Successive derivatives are
$$y'= - 2 \cos 2x,\; y''= 4 \sin 2x = 4 \quad @ \;x=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

because the denominator in the curvature formula

$$ \dfrac{y''}{(1+y^{'2})^{1.5}}$$

is unity.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can easily compute the curvature of $y=\sin(-2x)$ at $x=\pi/4$ as follows

$y=\sin (-2x)=-\sin(2x)$, $\ y'=-2\cos(2x)$, $\ y''=4\sin(2x)$

Substituting $x=\pi/4$, we get $y'(\pi/4)=0, \ y''(\pi/4)=4$

The curvature of $y=f(x)$ is given by
$$\left|\frac{y''}{(1+(y')^2)^{3/2}}\right|=\left|\frac{4}{(1+0^2)^{3/2}}\right|=\color{blue}{4}$$

Comment: Why downvote? Please consider to explain what is wrong with this answer.

Comment: -@Harish Chandra Rajpoot, even I face the same problem. It might be because your answer (although correct) doesn't clarify OP's doubt in the terminology proposed by them. I personally feel this answer is in between correct and wrong so I neither upvoted not did downvote.

Comment: @SarGe: Thanks for your comment. Actually I mentioned at the top of my answer that it is an alternate method which is quite simple to use. Yes it may not be addressing OP's doubts. Moreover, question's title is different from what OP wants to know.

Comment: There are always in the word...the haters :-)